I am trying to transpile code using the Abaplint's transpiler-CLI package. I am unable to identify and extract the transpiled code after running it
Everytime, despite running the code with a target directory, the code in image below creates a new output directory with a huge number of files and it becomes impossible to find the transpiled code even if it does exist in the output dir.
The image below is of the terminal, where I run the transpiler with specified input and output directories:

This is the link to the package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abaplint/transpiler-cli
I tried running it multiple times, played around with commands as I was expecting result to be populated with a single js file with the transpiled code. Something akin to the web results of the online transpiler for Abaplint.

Please "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question"
